# Inequality complex integral with $|f|\le 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Let $f:\mathbb C\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that 
>   $\,\lvert\, f(z)\rvert\le 1$ for all $z\in S^1\subset \mathbb C$. Prove that $$\left| \int_{\lvert z\rvert=1} f(z)\;\mathrm dz\right|\le \int_0^{2\pi}\lvert \sin(t)\rvert\,\mathrm dt.$$

I have tried to evaluate the integral on the left using the usual parametrization $\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$ and then using the triangle inequality for integrals, but with no success. Please, I'm looking for a hint.

Comment: $f$ is assume to be continuous or holomorphic?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Only continuous.

Comment: I think that I manage to get it right this time.

Comment: I cannot understand. The RHS integral is equal to $4$, while if we take $f=1$ constant, the LHS integral is $2 \pi$. So we get the wrong inequality $2 \pi \leq 4$.

Comment: @Crostul The LHS is $0$ when $f=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can view $f$ as a continuous, real-valued and $2\pi-$periodic function, absolutely bounded by 1.

Then
$$
\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1}f(z)\,dz=i\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)\,\mathrm{e}^{it}\,dt=r\,\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}.
$$
Then 
$$
\left|\,\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1}f(z)\,dz\,\right|=r=
\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\,\mathrm{e}^{i(t-\vartheta+\pi/2)}\,dt.
$$
Hence, if $g(t)=f(t+\vartheta-\pi/2)$, then 
$$
\left|\,\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1}f(z)\,dz\,\right|=
\int_0^{2\pi}g(t)\,\mathrm{e}^{it}\,dt=\int_0^{2\pi}g(t)\,\cos t\,dt,
$$
since $\,\,\mathrm{Im}\,\int_0^{2\pi}g(t)\,\mathrm{e}^{it}\,dt=0$. But the function 
$g$ is also a continuous, real-valued and $2\pi-$periodic function, absolutely bounded by 1.

Hence
$$
\left|\,\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1}f(z)\,dz\,\right|
=\int_0^{2\pi}g(t)\,\cos t\,dt\le \int_0^{2\pi}\lvert g(t)\rvert\,\lvert\cos t\rvert\,dt \le
\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert \cos t\rvert\,dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert \sin t\rvert\,dt.
$$
Note. In fact, the strict inequality is the one that holds, i.e,
$$
\left|\,\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1}f(z)\,dz\,\right|
<\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert \sin t\rvert\,dt,
$$
as
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}g(t)\,\cos t\,dt< \int_0^{2\pi}\lvert\cos t\rvert\,dt.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this.